# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' When i'm run a test in Python

Tags: python, flask, web

I'm working on a simple Flask app, and here's the current project structure:

```
|   .env
|   .gitignore
|   requirements.txt
|   
+---app
|   |   routes.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---blueprints
|       |   home.py
\---__tests__
        home_test.py
```

In my `home_test.py` file, I'm utilizing the Ward library to create a straightforward test. However, when attempting to import the `app` module, which contains a `__init__.py` file inside it, I encounter the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`.

This issue seems to be a common one. Here's the code snippet from the test:

```py
from ward import test
from splinter import Browser
from app import create_app

@test('Home page must be online')
def _():
    app = create_app()
    app.testing = True

    browser = Browser("flask", app=app)
    browser.visit('/')

    assert browser.is_text_present('Hello World')
```

Any guidance on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I attempted to run a simple test using the Ward library in my Flask app. In the test file `home_test.py`, I'm trying to import the `app` module, which contains a `__init__.py` file. However, I encountered a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'` error.

I expected the test to run successfully, initializing the Flask app and checking if the home page is online. The relevant test code snippet is as follows:

```py
from ward import test
from splinter import Browser
from app import create_app

@test('Home page must be online')
def _():
    app = create_app()
    app.testing = True

    browser = Browser("flask", app=app)
    browser.visit('/')

    assert browser.is_text_present('Hello World')
```